# Ubuntu 18.04 does not seem to be using my amd graphics card

Tags: drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics

I just switched my laptop from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 but it does not seem like Ubuntu is using the correct GPU. The integrated graphics card is the one being marked as VGA Controller, instead of my Radeon R7 M440. I searched for answers on the similar questions made here but it seems like my problem is a little bit different. I would be very glad if someone had a suggestion on how to proceed. Some more info:

```
Output of lshw -c video:
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:128 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
   description: Display controller
   product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 83
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:129 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0200000-d023ffff memory:d0240000-d025ffff
```

Output of:  lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+:.+([\S+:\S+])/' | grep VGA

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 [8086:5916] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```